# Continuous functions from $(X,d)$ to $(\mathbb{R},\mid\cdot\mid)$, open set

Tags: general-topology, analysis, low-dimensional-topology

> If $f$,$g$ are continuous functions from $(X,d)$ to $(\mathbb{R},\mid\cdot\mid)$. Show that $A=\{x \in X : 2f(x) > 3g(x)\}$ is open in $X$.

I understand that the continuous image of an open set is open in the metric spaces and vice versa. But I need help in proving this assertion. Thank you.

Comment: no, in general, the continuous **image** of an open set is not open. For example, the function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, given by $f(x) = 0$ is clearly continuous.

Comment: Yes sorry, only the continuous inverse image is open

Comment: IMO if you need to ask “how to prove that the sum of continuous functions is continuous", I suggest you go back to your notes or books for the definition of continuity and try to prove that, before coming back to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A =h^{-1}(0,\infty)$ where $h(x)=2f(x)-3g(x)$.